# Can i use same iOS developer certificate for Different Applications or Profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

I have released App1 in App store, I have a Developer certificate and multiple Developer profile for DEV/QA with same Developer certificate which is used for APP1.

Now I'm going to start App2 development. Can i use same Developer certificate used in App1 for App2 as well., Will there be any issue if i use same Developer certificate?

What is the best practice?

Thanks in Advance,

Saamy

Comment: Use the same certificate but create a new provisioning profile for the 2nd app.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Your developer certificate should be good for as many apps that you want to produce. If you want to separate the apps for in case to have others working with you on some of them, setting wild card is a good practice. So the answer is yes you can use the same Dev sett for both apps.

Comment: can i use the same apple development certificate for multiple appsconnects accounts?